# wget particular TEXT string from HTML side

Tags: wget, text, html

I would like to copy a particular line from an HTML-Site into a TXT file.

E.g. http://www.bafg.de/php/KOBLENZRHEINW.htm

Always contains the line:

```
Letzter gemessener Wert : 221 cm um 15:30 Uhr MEZ am 5.09.2017
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This command directs `wget`'s output to the console, `grep`s the chosen line and finally redirects it to a `.txt` file:

```
wget -q -O - "$@" http://www.bafg.de/php/KOBLENZRHEINW.htm | grep "Letzter gemessener Wert" > file.txt
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine, but as OP requested to save the line to a `.txt` file, redirect `grep`'s output with `> file.txt` or the like.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget http://www.bafg.de/php/KOBLENZRHEINW.htm && grep "Letzter gemessener Wert" KOBLENZRHEINW.htm > wert.txt
```

should do the trick if the line always begins with “Letzter gemessener Wert”. It downloads the `.htm` file, searches for the line and saves the output in `wert.txt`. Using just `>` will **overwrite** any existing file `wert.txt`, if you want to append the line to the file use `>>` instead.

However, zx485's way of piping the website text directly to `grep` is better than downloading the file first as in my solution above.